# in my project Glide library not load image

Tags: android, android-glide

java Code for load image fom URL

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
 .load("https://yildirim.bel.tr/uploads/haberler/4509c5f0-7498- 
             4932-85d4-767e48408299image.jpeg")
 .into(img);
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.googleandroid.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Comment: And I tried version 4.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class like that:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

// new since Glide v4
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
  // leave empty for now
}
```

Then call the Glide as:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("https://yildirim.bel.tr/uploads/haberler/4509c5f0-7498- 
         4932-85d4-767e48408299image.jpeg")
    .override(300, 200)
    .into(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

 Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. but not loading my image. it is load android icon